# Create an event within Google Calendar without Add Google Meet Video conferencing

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add an event within Google Calendar without getting **Google Meet Video conferencing**.

I'm trying that code:

```
Event event = new Event()
    .setSummary("Google I/O 2015");

DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setEnd(end);

EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
};
event.setAttendees("fullName@entreprise.tn");

EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);

String calendarId = "primary";
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

The new event is added, but with enabled **Google Meet Video conferencing**.

I just want to create a sample event **WITHOUT** `Google Meet Video conferencing`, and then let the user decide to add a Video Conference or not.

I want to have **1** instead of **2** like presented by that capture:

[image]
Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Big thanks.

Comment: If you look at the google's [guide on creating events through the API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events).
` You can also learn whether the user prefers to have Hangouts created for all their newly created events by checking the autoAddHangouts setting in the settings collection.`. Could you maybe check if that is enabled? because that may be the reason why the conference is added automatically.  Also from the same page `The conferenceData field can be used to read, copy, and clear existing conference details`. Can you delete the event after its creation?